# Is there any way to mark up a c function or obj-c method to identify it at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, c, attributes, introspection

I'm looking for something similar to attributes in Java, to use in an objective-c environment.

Suppose I have an implementation file with a bunch of methods defined. Is there any way I can mark them up such that I could find them with introspection at runtime? Something like;

```
##special_method
- (void)foo
{

}

##special_method
- (void)bar
{

}

// Not special
- (void)baz
{

}
```

As far as I know, nothing exists, and so the best idea I have is to prefix the method name with something common:

```
- (void)_special_foo
{

}

- (void)_special_bar
{

}

// Not special
- (void)baz
{

}
```

any other interesting ideas?

Comment: What are those dashed prefixing the function headers meant to tell us?

Comment: These are not headers... but i guess that doesn't matter. I assume you are referring to _special_bar, for example?  Well my thinking is that the _special_ is just a convention I could follow to identify the special nature of the methods I'm looking for.  This is less elegant than a true type of attribute so I'd like to avoid this approach if possible.

Comment: @alk it is the syntax for a member-method-start in Objective-C. If that throws you for loop you'd hurl biscuits on the messaging syntax.

Comment: Ah I see, so its about the `objective` part of the tags given, which is not part of my expertise ... thanks! @WhozCraig

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but as an "interesting" possible solution, you can use a global variable that is set to a unique value identifying a specific function on entry (and optionally resetting on exit), or you can use a stack to trace these values that you can inspect at any time.

Comment: Umm, so you would call every method on an object, without regard to the side effects or preconditions involved, just to see if it sets some global variable?

Comment: @Arkku: it may help if you think it an adapted form of profiling for real/run-time inspection

Answer (score 1):

Apple's suggestion to identify private methods is to give a unique prefix:

> Names of most private methods in the Cocoa frameworks have an
>   underscore prefix (for example, `_fooData`) to mark them as private.
>   From this fact follow two recommendations.
>
> - Don’t use the underscore character as a prefix for your private
>     methods. Apple reserves this convention.
> - If you are subclassing a
>     large Cocoa framework class (such as `NSView` or `UIView`) and you want to
>     be absolutely sure that your private methods have names different from
>     those in the superclass, you can add your own prefix to your private
>     methods. The prefix should be as unique as possible, perhaps one based
>     on your company or project and of the form "XX_". So if your project
>     is called Byte Flogger, the prefix might be `BF_addObject:`

I suppose you could use a similar scheme to mark certain methods as special for some sort of runtime manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT start any method names with a single leading underscore.  That's an Apple internal coding convention to keep their method names from colliding with yours.  If you want to differentiate your method names, just use a common prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are implementing the class, why not just define a method that returns a list of the special methods in that class? If you need to do subclasses, have them get the parent's list and add to it.